# Prove for all n∈N $1^2+3^2+5^2+...+(2n-1)^2=\frac{4n^3-n}{3}$

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

> Prove for all n∈N $1^2+3^2+5^2+...+(2n-1)^2=\frac{4n^3-n}{3}$
>   This is what I got, but I dont think it is right.[image]

Comment: Look at what you need to prove carefully. The statement you have tried to prove, and then got stuck, is *not* $P(2k+1)$, because the left hand side is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit confused as to what you mean. Which step is this in?

Comment: The answer below clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are dealing with a sum of squares seems to have completely disappeared in the step.

Here's what you need:

$$1^2+3^2+...+(2k-1)^2+(2k+1)^2= \text{ (Inductive Hypothesis)}$$

$$\frac{4k^3-k}{3}+(2k+1)^2= $$

$$\frac{4k^3-k}{3}+\frac{3(2k+1)^2}{3}= $$

$$\frac{4k^3-k+3(2k+1)^2}{3}= $$

$$\frac{4k^3-k+3(4k^2+4k+1)}{3}= $$

$$\frac{4k^3-k+12k^2+12k+3}{3}= $$

$$\frac{4k^3+12k^2+12k+3-k+1-1}{3}= $$

$$\frac{4k^3+12k^2+12k+4-(k+1)}{3}$$

$$\frac{4(k^3+3k^2+3k+1)-(k+1)}{3}$$

$$\frac{4(k+1)^3-(k+1)}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) = \frac{4n^3-n}{3}$ is what you want to prove for all n. So I'm skipping the base case and moving to the inductive step

In the inductive step you supposed the formula is true for n, and try to prove it for n + 1

so now what we want to prove is $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k-1) = \frac{4(n+1)^3-(n+1)}{3}$$

For summation, these cases are often quite easy for simple induction. remove the last term from the summation (that is, the "(n+1)th" term) and add it normally

you'll end up with

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (2k-1)= \sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) + [2(n+1)-1] $$

But because of our assumption, we know that the summation on the right equals our formula, so

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1) + [2(n+1)-1] = \frac{4n^3-n}{3} + [2(n+1)-1] $$

The rest is just ordering everything to try and reach the original formula